# How do I create a list with changing values?

Tags: list, finance

if I want to do a finance calculation by defining a function with the parameters:

```
def FV(x,r,t):
```

where x is the initial amount, r is the rate and t is the amount of years, how do I write a function which gives me a list of all the amounts in the respective years?

my best try up until now is:

```py
def FV(x, r, t):
    """
    inputs:
    x = amount invested
    r = rate (in % p.a.) accrued on the account each year
    t = number of years

    returns a list "acc" with amount on the account at 0, 1, ... t
    """
    acc = []
 
    value = x*(1+r/100)**t
    for years in range(t+1):
        if years <= t:
            acc.append(value)
            

    return acc

print(FV(100,5,7))
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you want to do, but it sounds like you are looking for an amortization table, not future value.

If so, try something like this:

```
periods = 3
int_rate = .1
account = [100]
balance = account[0]

def amortize(periods,int_rate,balance):
    while periods>0:
        current_int = balance * int_rate        
        balance = balance+current_int
        account.append(balance)        
        periods -=1
amortize(periods,int_rate,balance)
account
```

Output:

```
[100, 110.0, 121.0, 133.1]
```

Comment: Thanks very much! Thats close to what I tried to do but I need just the actual balances in a list for example account = []. How can I just get a list with e.g. account = [100, 110, 121, 133.10, ...]